# .htaccess redirection failure for certain paths

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I have come accross a particularly vexing problem with my .htaccess file. I am using a standard redirection for running all requests through the index.php like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

      #make all direct requests to /index.php go to example.com/ instead
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

      #redirect everything to index.php for url parsing and routing
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Is there any reason that a url such as:

```
www.example.com/error/view/404
```

would bypass the redirection and get the default Apache "access denied" or "object does not exist" errors? Is there some sort of fix for this or is that path something that Apache doesn't allow for some reason?

Comment: What does going to `http://www.example.com/index.php?url=error/view/404` result in?

Comment: That results in the correct page being displayed. using the url in the question doesn't even hit the index.php file, it gets intercepted by Apache before the redirect.

Comment: Is the htaccess file in your document root? Is there a directory called `/error` or `/error/view`?

Comment: The htaccess file is in the document root. There are no directories at all, just index.php and .htaccess in the document root.